# How to install gstreamer 1.16 on ubuntu, which already have gstreamer 1.14

Tags: c++, c, gstreamer

Is there ant way I can upgrade to gstreamer 1.16 from 1.14
or The way I know is: download .deb file and dpkg --install .deb
But doing this have other dependency...like libc6 need to >=2.29
.
.
Any perfect solution to do so (upgrade to gstreamer 1.16 from 1.14)

OS/relese details:
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.

Comment: Extra detail should be added to your question, not replied via comment. Also note though, your system is behind on updates (if it reports 18.04.3, ie. note http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/02/12/ubuntu-18-04-4-lts-released/ and installed systems would have reported 18.04.4 before that date as it signifies the release of the ISO only)

Comment: Thanks!!
I am upgarding to 18.04.4
but with gstreamer how  upgrade to gstreamer 1.16 from 1.14